# Accessing MySQL database via Mac OSX 10.9

Tags: mysql, r, macos

I've been scouring the internet only to not find any answers as to how to connect to MySQL via RODBC (or ODBC in general) on Mac OSX 10.9.

Apparently iODBC is deprecated as of OSX 10.8?

I've installed unixODBC via Homebrew. So that portion is covered.

Where should I look to getting (or building) MySQL drivers for 10.9? The lastest MySQL dmg or tarball I find on the MySQL Connector site is for OSX 10.7 (and that doesn't install properly). I've tried pulling the lib files out and linking them via the odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini files for unixODBC but isql still fails.

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: There is also RMySQL. It does not require ODBC.

Comment: I have mainly used RMySQL on Windows and Linux but I have found it worked well in both those settings.  I would not agree your characterization of it at all.

Comment: I use RMySQL on OS X 10.9.2 (and previous) with R 3.0.3 (and previous) all the time. Is there some constraint requiring ODBC?

Comment: Good comments on the status of ODBC on mac here:
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419243/rodbc-to-connect-to-sql-server-on-mavericks